# Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

Tags: java, android

Estoy trabajando con android en una app que esta desarrollada para android 5 en adelante el problema es que se quiere hacer compatible con 4.4.2 y al ejecutar el apk en una dispositivo 4.4.2 sale el siguiente error.

Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

el gradle de la app es el siguiente

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'

}
```

agrege lo que indica la liga que se muestra y simplemente no me funciona, espero que puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed
>   64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at

Esto se soluciona habilitando multidex desde tu `build.gradle` :

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    } 
}
```

Revisa el documento de la documentación : [**Configurar tu app para Multidex con gradle.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=es-419)

> Los archivos de aplicación de Android (APK) contienen archivos de
>   código de bytes ejecutables en forma de archivos Dalvik Executable
>   (Dex), que contienen el código compilado empleado para ejecutar tu
>   app. La especificación de Dalvik Executable limita la cantidad total
>   de métodos a los que se puede hacer referencia en un archivo Dex a 65
>   536, incluidos los métodos del framework de Android, de biblioteca y
>   de tu propio código. En el contexto de la informática, el término
>   Kilo, K, denota 1024 (o 2^10). Debido a que 65 536 es igual a 64 X
>   1024, este límite se denomina **“límite de referencia de 64K”**.
>
> **Para superar este límite, debes configurar el proceso de compilación
>   de tu app para que genere más de un archivo Dex, lo que se conoce como
>   configuración MultiDex.**

---

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled = true //*** Agregar!
    }
```